# Is it possible to have a function(-name) as a template parameter in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, function

I don't want function pointer overhead, I just want the same code for two different functions with the same signature:

```
void f(int x);
void g(int x);

...

template<typename F>
void do_work()
{
  int v = calculate();
  F(v);
}

...

do_work<f>();
do_work<g>();
```

Is this possible?

---

To clear up possible confusion: With "template parameter" I mean *the parameter/argument to the template* and ***not*** a function parameter whose type is templated.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One approach that is highly likely to generate the direct function call, because it gives the compiler no option, is to use a static member function:

```
struct F { static void func(int x) { /*whatever*/ } };
struct G { static void func(int x) { /*whatever*/ } };

template<class T>
void do_work() {
    T::func(calculate());
}
```

No function pointers, no temporaries, and no unnecessary `this`. I guarantee nothing, of course, but generated code should be reasonable even with optimization disabled.

Comment: +1 : very nice solution. Not applicable in the problem that backs my question, but very nice as a general solution!

Answer (score 26):

Your idea's ok, but you're not passing in a type but a value (specifically, a function pointer>.  Alternatively, pass a template policy providing functions - it's a good idea to read Modern C++ Design by Andrei Alexandrescu.

```
#include <iostream>

int f(int x) { return 2 * x; }
int g(int x) { return -3 * x; }

typedef int (*F)(int);

template<F f> 
int do_work() 
{ 
    return f(7);
} 

int main()
{
    std::cout << do_work<f>() << '\n'
              << do_work<g>() << '\n'; 
}
```

OR

```
int calculate() { return 4; }

struct F { int do_something_with(int x) { return 2 * x; } };
struct G { int do_something_with(int x) { return -3 * x; } };
// or, make these functions static and use Operator::do_something_with() below...

template<typename Operation> 
int do_work() 
{ 
    int v = calculate(7);
    return Operation().do_something_with(v);
} 

int main()
{
    std::cout << do_work<F>() << '\n'
              << do_work<G>() << '\n'; 
}
```

Comment: +1 for showing a decent solution with fn-pointers. But I assume this would still incur some runtime overhead to dereference the fn pointer vs. a copy&paste version for do_work_f() and do_work_g() ... ?

Comment: @Martin: it's a crucial question - all up the optimiser.  I wouldn't bet on this being inlined, whereas I would bet on a policy template member....

Comment: @Tony - could you maybe link in some resource that (approx.) describes a template policy thing in the way you would adopt it for this problem?

Comment: `return Operation(7);` should be `return Operation()(7);`

Comment: +1; Just like Martin asked, it would be great to have your implementation of the policy template member. I'm still struggling with much of the "C++ Modern Design" book which I don't really grasp. Any concrete application example is dearly welcome.

Comment: @Martin: I changed the template policy version above a little to more directly mirror the question.  While it is a little more verbose, I tend to use function names for the things the policy provides - it is common for there to be more than one function in each policy, and it often makes for more comprehensible code.  , @Stephane Rolland: for a more great concrete application, consider `std::sort`'s acceptance of a less-than policy... by not hard-coding operator<, it allows you to say compare dereferenced pointers or reverse the sort order.  Is that a useful practical example?

Answer (score 9):

You can have pointers to functions as template parameters, but function objects are more "C++ish". However, you can write your function template in a way that accepts both variants:

```
#include <iostream>

void f(int x)
{
    std::cout << "inside function f\n";
}

struct g
{
    void operator()(int x)
    {
        std::cout << "inside function object g\n";
    }
};

template <typename Functor>
void do_work(Functor fun)
{
    fun(42);
}

int main()
{
    // template argument is automatically deduced
    do_work(&f);
    // but we could also specify it explicitly
    do_work<void(*)(int)>(&f);

    // template argument is automatically deduced
    do_work(g());
    // but we could also specify it explicitly
    do_work<g>(g());
}
```

Here, the name `Functor` hints at any type that is callable via `f(x)` syntax. Functions support this syntax naturally, and in the case of function objects, `f(x)` is syntactic sugar for `f.operator()(x)`.

Comment: +1 ...and they compile to a direct call, without function-pointer calling overhead at runtime.

Comment: @Doug: that's not guaranteed. Highly likely, though, since e.g. `std::sort` benefits a lot from that optimization.

Comment: Your implementation there will match the `typename Fun` parameter to the function prototype `void(*)(int)`, and then use the same instantiation for both calls - not inlining: that's why you actually end up passing the function pointer as a run-time argument to `do_work(Fun fun)`.

Comment: +1 - does not deserve -1: But it *could* accept a function object just fine; this is the flexible, standard approach to use.

Comment: @MSalters - definitely not guaranteed. I misread the FredOverflow's answer slightly - I thought FredOverflow had `do_work` accepting a template non-type function pointer argument, as the question indicates, rather than a template type argument. The non-type arguments are even more likely to compile into a direct call.

Comment: @Martin: I have updated my answer, would you reconsider the downvote?

Comment: The address operator `&` is superfluous in your `do_work(&f)` call - i.e. `do_work(f)` is equivalent.

Answer (score 6):

No, you need to wrap the functions in a wrapper class with `operator()`. Here is an example:

```
class Functor_f
{
public:
    void operator()(int x)
    {
    }
};

class Functor_g
{
    public:
    void operator()(int x)
    {
    }
};



template<typename F>
void do_work()
{
  F f;
 int v = calculate();
  f(v);
}


int main()
{
    do_work<Functor_f>();
    do_work<Functor_g>();

}
```

You can use `std::ptr_fun` to do this wrapping automatically for you. For example:

```
void f(int x)
{
}

void g(int x)
{
}

template<typename F>
void do_work(F f)
{
 int v = calculate();
  f(v);
}


int main()
{
    do_work(std::ptr_fun(f));
    do_work(std::ptr_fun(g));

}
```

Comment: The first example (without `std::ptr_fun`) gives a much better chance of actual inlining -- and (although of course it depends on a lot) is thus most likely fastest, somewhat counter-intuitive perhaps. Cheers,

Answer (score 2):

It's OK in C++17 with the `template<auto V>`syntax.

```cpp
void f(int x);
void g(int x);

template<auto F>
void do_work(int x)
{
  F(x);
}

void test(){
    do_work<f>(1);
    do_work<g>(2);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/c9E4q345x

Comment: Can I do it with class member function? something like `do_work<A::f>(&a);`

Answer (score 1):

With any modern C++ compiler you don't pay the function pointer overhead when the function pointer value is known at compile time, like in your example, because the compiler then replaces the indirection with a direct function call.

Consider your example code, slightly modified:

```
void f(int x);
void g(int x);
int calculate();

template<typename F>
void do_work(F f)
{
    int v = calculate();
    f(v);
}

static void trabajar(void (f)(int))
{
    int v = calculate();
    f(v);
}

void foo()
{
    do_work(f);
    do_work(g);
}

void bar()
{
    trabajar(f);
    trabajar(g);
}

void baz()
{
    f(calculate());
    g(calculate());
}
```

For all the `foo()`, `bar()` and `baz()` variants GCC 12.1 generates the same direct function invoking code:

```
        sub     rsp, 8
        call    calculate()
        mov     edi, eax
        call    f(int)
        call    calculate()
        add     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, eax
        jmp     g(int)
```

See also: [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/7Kh6hqMxE)

Notes:

- `foo()` and `bar()` invoke `f()` and `g()` via function pointers
- `baz()` invokes `f()` and `g()` directly
- for you use case it isn't necessary to templatize your `do_work()` function, i.e. `trabajar()` is the non-template version that only accepts function pointers
- templating `do_work()` like this has the advantage that you can also supply some compatible function object (functor) instead of a function pointer
- when templating `do_work()` like this and supplying a function address as its argument (like in `foo()`), the template parameter `F` is type-inferred to `void (*)(int)`, i.e. a function pointer type

It's perhaps worth mentioning that even when using a C++ function object there isn't really a guarantee that your C++ compiler inlines the classes function call operator. However, any serious C++ will do it.

Answer (score 0):

Another example about the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77170791) by @Ignacio Sharpe and @Martin Ba, and the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4013532/12529885) by @Tony Delroy

```cpp
struct AA {
    void m() {}
    void n() {}
}aa;

template<auto F>
void do_work(AA *ptr)
{
    (ptr->*F)();
}

void test(){
    do_work<&AA::m>(&aa);
    do_work<&AA::n>(&aa);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/cazYc5qz9